# Using UIDocumentPickerViewController to import text in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I'm currently taking an iOS development course and as part of my project, I'm tasked with using `UIDocumentPickerViewController` to import text. Every example I've found is either a) written in Objective-C or b) is for importing `UIImage` files.

**How do I set the delegate method for a text file?**

*Here's what I've got so far:*

I have the iCloud capability set up. **Works**

The delegate is specified, as follows:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UIDocumentPickerDelegate
```

I have the property set up for the type of text I'm trying to import:

```
@IBOutlet weak var newNoteBody: UITextView!
```

I have an `IBAction` setup as follows:

```
@IBAction func importItem(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    var documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypeText as NSString], inMode: UIDocumentPickerMode.Import)
    documentPicker.delegate = self
    documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen
    self.presentViewController(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

I can't figure out what the line should be below. The documentation on Apple's website isn't clear and every example I've found is in Objective-C or is for images.

```
// MARK: - UIDocumentPickerDelegate Methods

func documentPicker(controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAtURL url: NSURL) {
    if controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerMode.Import {
        // What should be the line below?
        self.newNoteBody.text = UITextView(contentsOfFile: url.path!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Got it! I had two problems:

1) Apple says you've gotta specify UTI's in an array. I called the documentType a `KUTTypeText`. It should be a `"public.text"` in the array.

Here's Apple's listing of [Uniform Text Identifiers (UTIs)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html)

```
@IBAction func importItem(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    var documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.text"], inMode: UIDocumentPickerMode.Import)
    documentPicker.delegate = self
    documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen
    self.presentViewController(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

The second problem was a syntactic issue on the Delegate, solved with this:

```
// MARK: - UIDocumentPickerDelegate Methods

func documentPicker(controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAtURL url: NSURL) {
    if controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerMode.Import {
        // This is what it should be
        self.newNoteBody.text = String(contentsOfFile: url.path!)
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that you use .modalPresenationStyle, does it actually work? For some reason, even if I use PageSheet, the picker is still displayed in Full Screen mode

Comment: I want to pick multiple files via document picker but allowsMultipleSelection not working on UIDocumentPickerViewController, please help, thanks in advance